# personalization of the analytic index

Tags: indexing, imakeidx

how can i have an analytic index like this?

[image]

I would also remove the number of the page in the first page of the analytic index (indicated from arrow). if you notice, is wrong to even the reference of hyperref at the analytic index when you open the file with acrobat reader how can i fix it?

thanks at all

```
\documentclass[10pt,%                      % corpo del font principale
               a4paper,%                   % carta A4
%               draft,%                    % evidenzia le righe Overfull hbox
               twoside,%
%               oneside,%
               openright,%                % fronte-retro
%               openany%                    % solo fronte
               ]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                   % codifica dei font:
                                           % NOTA BENE! richiede una distribuzione *completa* di LaTeX

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                % codifica di input; anche [latin1] va bene
                                           % NOTA BENE! va accordata con le preferenze dell'editor

\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}        % per scrivere in italiano e in inglese;
                                           % l'ultima lingua (l'italiano) risulta predefinita
\usepackage{emptypage}                     % pagine vuote senza testatina e piede di pagina

\usepackage{makeidx}                       % Indice analitico
\makeindex

\usepackage[italian]{varioref}             % riferimenti completi della pagina

\usepackage{hyperref}                      % collegamenti ipertestuali

\usepackage{bookmark}                      % segnalibri

\begin{document}
%*******************************************************************
\mainmatter%              Materiale principale
%*******************************************************************
Lorem\index{Lorem} ipsum dolor\index{dolor} sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce quis justo felis, nec eleifend leo. Nulla aliquet est a dui placerat hendrerit.
%\pdfbookmark{Indice analitico}{Indice analitico}
\cleardoublepage
%\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\indexname}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way:

```
\documentclass[10pt,%                      % corpo del font principale
               a4paper,%                   % carta A4
%               draft,%                    % evidenzia le righe Overfull hbox
               twoside,%
%               oneside,%
               openright,%                % fronte-retro
%               openany%                    % solo fronte
               ]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                   % codifica dei font:
                                           % NOTA BENE! richiede una distribuzione *completa* di LaTeX

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                % codifica di input; anche [latin1] va bene
                                           % NOTA BENE! va accordata con le preferenze dell'editor

\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}        % per scrivere in italiano e in inglese;
                                           % l'ultima lingua (l'italiano) risulta predefinita
\usepackage{emptypage}                     % pagine vuote senza testatina e piede di pagina

\usepackage{imakeidx}                      % Indice analitico
\makeindex[intoc]                          % L'indice analitico va nell'indice generale
\indexsetup{firstpagestyle=empty}          % Niente numero di pagina nella prima dell'indice analitico

\usepackage[italian]{varioref}             % riferimenti completi della pagina

\usepackage{hyperref}                      % collegamenti ipertestuali

\usepackage{bookmark}                      % segnalibri

\begin{document}
%*******************************************************************
\mainmatter%              Materiale principale
%*******************************************************************
Lorem\index{Lorem} ipsum dolor\index{dolor} sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce quis justo felis, nec eleifend leo. Nulla aliquet est a dui placerat hendrerit.
\printindex
\end{document}
```

If this file is called `filename.tex`, you have also to prepare a text file called `filename.mst` in the same directory, containing

```
heading_prefix   "\\section*{"
heading_suffix   "}\\hrule\\nopagebreak\\vskip1ex\n"
headings_flag       1
```

This will print headings for each letter group.

Using `imakeidx` frees you from running `makeindex` manually.

Comment: Thank you Greg ! :) i have try but no headings :S this is my .mst file http://www61.zippyshare.com/v/12767111/file.html is correct?

Comment: @FormlessCloud The name of the file must be *the same* as the main file, with extension `.mst` instead of `.tex`